# Необходима помощь со статическими файлами в django

Tags: django

Прохожу туториал по Django 2.1 и у меня возникла проблема с подключением статического Css файл. Привожу код подключения статического css.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "blog_site/css/blog_site.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h2>My blog</h2>
        <p>This is my blog.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Код в файле css не выполняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, измените структуру каталогов. Статика не должна лежать в каталоге шаблонов

```
blog
└───blog_site
    ├───static
    │   └───css
    │           blog_site.css
    │
    └───templates
```

Во-вторых, измените тег в шаблоне на `{% static "css/blog_site.css" %}`

Comment: Если вам не составит труда, вы можете объяснить почему статик файлы должны храниться в каталоге static? Так по дефолту в django?

Comment: Это поведение по умолчанию для `AppDirectoriesFinder`. Можно и по любым другим каталогам разложить, но тогда придётся сделать [дополнительные настройки](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/).